# problems installing RestKit - RKURL undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, restkit

Installed RestKit via command line git into my Xcode 4.5.2 project.

Followed all the install directions to a T.  A couple of problems have presented themselves

1. When I try to link the libary to binaries and select libRestKit.a,.. libRestKit.a shows up as red.
2. when I try to use RestKit in my project, I import RestKit.h, it builds just fine.  IDE sees a whole bunch of RK* classes.   However, whenever I try to create an instance of RKURL, it gives me an Undeclared identifier..

does anyone have any clues? thanks in advance!

Comment: what version of RestKit are you using? the newer v0.20?

Comment: This is *in no way* related to Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

1. I recommend you using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) to manage your libraries. CocoaPods will save your life by magically installing and maintaining the libs for you, so you will not face the problem of linking library to binaries.
2. if you want to use RKURL, you have to downgrade your RestKit to v0.10.3. there is no "RKURL" in v0.20.0. if you are using CocoaPods to maintain libraries, you can assign the version in your Podfile:`pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.10.3'`

Comment: Although you can downgrade to use old RestKit, it's not recommended by the development team of RestKit. Unless you are maintaining project that already uses old version of RestKit, studying the new version and using it may be a better choice.